# Show I use "before" or "until" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence

> I'm not really sure how long I was in there. All I know is that I didn't come
>   out from the toilet **before/until** I'd thrown up four times.

Should I use *before* or *until*? (I third option is also welcome).

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference for ELU, but it would have been okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: janoChen, you can also use the word *weed* instead of *peed*.

Comment: “Until having peed” sounds quite clumsy to me. _Until_ is normally followed by a finite clause, not a participial clause, so a more natural phrasing would be “until I'd peed”.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks, so I should also write "before I'd peed?"

Comment: _Before_ can be used with both finite and participial clauses, so either works fine there. To my ear, though, _until_ is a better fit for what you're intending to say here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers good thing I didn't use the original sentence. Where I used the word jack off. I guess my intent to make the example more appropriate wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, how about now?

Comment: janoChen, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wee_2

Comment: @janoChen: Fair enough. I've cancelled my downvote and deleted the previous comments about that. I stand by my closevote because I think this is an ELL question, as I said originally. But if other people want to see it asked and asked here that's up to them - I've only got one vote (or two, if you count the fact that I have the rep to downvote *and* closevote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What to Use

Here is a chart of uses

Event-1 **until** Event-2:

Event-1 continues up to the time when Event-2 begins.

Event-1 **before** Event-2:

Event-1 occurs prior to the time when Event-2 begins.

Not Event-1 UNTIL Event-2:

Event-1 occurs just at the time when Event-2 begins

Not Event-1 BEFORE Event-2:

Event-1 occurs at any time after the time when Event-2 begins.

So if you are using **until** you are saying something like

> Immediately after I peed four times, I left the bathroom.

And with **before**

> I left the bathroom sometime after peeing four times

It depends on the context

### Other Options

I generally wouldn't use *I didn't come out before* because it is a bit confusing.
If that is what you are trying to convey I would use:

> I'm not really sure how long I was in there.  All I know is that I finally made it out after peeing four times.

It is all up to preference though